# How do I display an alert() off of a google maps 'marker' click?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

What I have:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lQXG.png)
...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {

  this.map.setZoom(15);
  this.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  console.log('hello world');
  this.presentAlert(); // ERROR core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: 
  //this.presentAlert is not a function

});
```

...

What I want:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK84y.png)

My code expanded:
...

```
 public addMarker(lat: number, lng: number) {
    //let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.576, -158.271); // hiking 
    // spot

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: latLng
    });

    this.markers.push(marker); // catch 'em all

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {

      this.map.setZoom(15);
      this.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      console.log('hello world');
      this.presentAlert(); // ERROR core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: 
      // this.presentAlert is not a function

    });

  }

presentAlert() {
        this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: 'Alert',
          subHeader: 'Subtitle',
          message: 'This is an alert message.',
          buttons: ['OK']
        }).then(alert=> {
          alert.present();
        });

      }
```

...

I've tried a few other things but for me, intuitively, this makes most sense. Help? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local vartiable for `this`

Because `this` changes its value based on the context it's runs.

```
public addMarker(lat: number, lng: number) {
  ...

  let that = this;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    ...

    that.presentAlert();
  });

}
```